# I have to execute my code twice for it to work

Tags: excel, vba

So I have two problems, the first one I kind of managed to solve it.

1. When I run my code the first time (It gives me error 9, subscript out of range):
   - It copies range of column E (Raw List)
   - It pastes range of column E on column K
   - It does not remove duplicates
   - It dosent get in to the loop
2. When I run my code for the second time (It gives me no error)
   - It does remove duplicates
   - It does go in to the loop and works fine

Discoveries:
I have to execute my code twice for it to work.
I discovered that if before removing duplicates, I select the range, it will remove the duplicates on the first execution, but it wont go in to the loop till the second execution.

```
Sub Distribuir()
Dim FinalRowE As Integer
Dim FinalRowK As Integer
Dim Cell As Range
Dim TabList As Range
Dim RawList As Range
Dim UnDuplicateList As Range
Dim WS As Worksheet

FinalRowE = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
FinalRowK = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

Set RawList = Range(Cells(FinalRowE, "E"), Cells(1, "E"))
RawList.Copy Range("K1")

Set UnDuplicateList = Range(Cells(1, "K"), Cells(FinalRowK, "K"))
'I discovered that if I put UnduplicateList.Select It will remove duplicates at first execution.
UnDuplicateList.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo       

Set TabList = Range(Cells(2, "K"), Cells(FinalRowK, "K"))
    For Each Cell In TabList
        If Cell.Value <> "" Then
            Sheets(Cell.Value).Visible = True
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Start by fully qualifying your range references to ensure the commands are always referring to the desired worksheet. `With` statement is handy here so you don't have to keep repeating the qualifiers.

Comment: if I can guess, your problem is in `FinalRowK = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row` line. you should probably put it after the copy line. Also the loop needs updated `FinalRowK` after deduplication

Comment: Also adding `on error resume next` or something where you try to do `Sheets(Cell.Value).Visible = True` can be helpful

Comment: Wow Thank You all for ur responses. All helpfull! @milo5m was right, but dont know why? Can you give me a hint or tell me what I should study to understand that?

Comment: Number of rows change before and after copying/deduplicating

Comment: nicee it makes perfect sence, thank you!!! @milo5m